# Tilde/backtick key is coming out as section/plus-minus key on my external keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, imac

I've seen a few answers to this, but is there anyway to fix this without downloading anything? I've already tried changing the keyboard type but it has not worked. On my Magic keyboard this isn't a problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add photos of both keyboards? Those two keys are in different physical places on ISO [EU] & ANSI [US] keyboard types. Have you tried forcing Manula recognition from the Keyboard control panel?

Comment: What input source are you using? System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources.